# How can I achieve this price REGEX with REGEXMATCH in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is the deal,

I want to allow user to enter this kind of entries in my **price** column:

```
1 or 1234 or 1234,1 or 1234,1234 ...
```

So I've used this regex which works fine with REGEX101's website

```
^\d+(,\d+)?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/D5dAXx/1

only problem is that it doesn't work well with Google spreadsheet's function **REGEXMATCH**

```
=REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(C2), "^\d+(,\d+)?$")
```

for example this entries do not match

```
1
12
1,123
```

when this entries matches correctly

```
1,1
1,12
```

Why is that and what could be the correct REGEX?

Comment: Same problem it forbids my entry and data validation doesn't work

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by "doesn't work well"? It works for me.

Comment: I've just edited my post

Comment: I get `TRUE` for all the 5 inputs.

Comment: even if you put it as a data validation criteria?

Comment: Ok, tried as a data validation criterion (selected *Custom formula is*) and it still works.

Comment: Wow it doesn't for me at all in fact it's even worse when I put the formula directly in a cell and try to match the value of another cell. I'll have a deeper look at it. do you think you can share your spreadsheet?

Comment: Try https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HbisRJWH-acrHs1qm-r3zLCt6RxXLf6Fx4CCKLTUyvE/edit#gid=0, see Columns H and F.

Comment: ok I had done a mistake with the formula in cell and now it works fine but still not working in data validation. weird but I'm asking myself if it''s not a formatting problem. Thx for the spreadsheet

Comment: this was a formatting problem, I'll just answer my post and many thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was a bad format on the column.

When I entered:

```
12,1234
```

the format turned it into

```
12.1234
```

which was not matching my REGEXMATCH.

This means data validation criterion comes after the formatting in google's spreadsheets